# FlashVars Not Working But Query String Is

Tags: actionscript-3, flashvars

Some advise please.

I have a FLA in CS5 using AS3 and I can get Query String to work to pass variables but not FlashVars (I am not trying to use them both at the same time).

I have HTML below that adds the SWF:

```
<!-- Extract from http://www.[domain]/flash.html -->
    <div id="flashContent">
        <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="700" height="600" id="SWF" align="middle">
            <param name="movie" value="http://[subdomain].[domain]/swf.swf?var1=var1value"> <!-- This is working -->
            <param name="FlashVars" value="var1=var1value"> <!-- This is NOT working -->
            <param name="quality" value="high">
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
            <param name="play" value="true">
            <param name="loop" value="true">
            <param name="wmode" value="window">
            <param name="scale" value="showall">
            <param name="menu" value="true">
            <param name="devicefont" value="false">
            <param name="salign" value="">
            <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://[subdomain].[domain]/swf.swf?var1=var1value" width="700" height="600">
                <param name="movie" value="http://[subdomain].[domain]/swf.swf?var1=var1value"> <!-- This is working -->
                <param name="FlashVars" value="var1=var1value"> <!-- This is NOT working -->
                <param name="quality" value="high">
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff">
                <param name="play" value="true">
                <param name="loop" value="true">
                <param name="wmode" value="window">
                <param name="scale" value="showall">
                <param name="menu" value="true">
                <param name="devicefont" value="false">
                <param name="salign" value="">
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain">
            <!--<![endif]-->
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player">
                </a>
            <!--[if !IE]>-->
            </object>
            <!--<![endif]-->
        </object>
    </div>
```

In the FLA I have the following:

```
   try {
        flashVars = LoaderInfo(this.root.loaderInfo).parameters;
    }catch (error:Error) {
        errorBox.appendText(error.toString());
    }
```

I then use the passed information by using:

```
flashVars.var1;
```

As noted in the comments in the HTML `<param name="movie" value="http://[subdomain].[domain]/swf.swf?var1=var1value">` works but `<param name="FlashVars" value="var1=var1value">` does not.

My understanding is that `<param name="FlashVars" value="var1=var1value">` is considered better practise. Is this the case and why, but more importantly can anyone tell me why it is not working?

Comment: Not sure, looks correct as far as I know. Just a guess but, have you tried "flashvars" in one or both of the params?

Comment: Good call, alas no better. :(

Comment: I had a thought that it might be to do with the SWF being loaded from a sub-domain but I have tried this and it has not made any difference. :(

Comment: Have you traced out all of your objects? (this,root,loaderInfo,params) in an attempt to see where things are breaking down? This swf isn't being loaded by another swf is it? Just throwing out some ideas...

Comment: this.root.loaderInfo is fine but I do not know how to debug a SWF that was loaded from HTML so this.root.loaderInfo.parameters appears as an unpopulated object. I feel that it must be right though as query string works.